# Shows grub command lines when I boot up Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I deleted the drive allocated to Ubuntu (OS other than Windows 8.1) and merged with existing drive in Windows 8.1. However, when I try to boot, it also shows the Ubuntu starts menu. After clicking the Ubuntu boot menu it shows the some command line interface such as

```
grub>
```

How do I remove the Ubuntu option permanently and reinstall Ubuntu?

Comment: look like you remove it in a wrong way and GRUB bootloader is still as a default bootloader. Since you have Windows there, try to use Windows recovery and do startup repair.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an EFI-mode boot, you can:

1. Boot anything you can boot, such as an Ubuntu installation disk in its "try before installing" mode.
2. Identify the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition). This is normally the first or second partition on the disk, although it can be something else. It's a FAT partition with a "boot flag" set in `parted` or GParted, or with a type code of EF00 in GPT fdisk (`gdisk`, `sgdisk`, or `cgdisk`).
3. Mount the ESP.
4. On the ESP, delete the `EFI/ubuntu` directory tree.